# Simple question about locally finitely presentable categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ denote small finitely complete categories.

Does every cocontinuous functor between locally finitely presentable categories $F:\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set})\to\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{D},\mathbf{Set})$ come from a (unique?) finite-limit preserving functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: No, you have to require that $F$ preserves fp objects. I think that you will find a counterexample from this hint.

Comment: @HeinrichD Thanks! Is that a no to uniqueness or a no to even the existence of a functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: This is no to existence.